# Python:a list or a dictionary for a tree of elements?

Tags: python

I have this data I want to plot, and I was wondering what will be better to use (with python) a dictionary or a list?
My variables can be described as follow:

```
for user in range(1,4):
   for name in range(1,16):
      for level in range(1,7):
         for year in range(1,6):
            for item in range(1,5):
               output.append(user, name, level, year, item)
```

This is just the structure of my data (which I want to plot after loading this process in a csv), and by range I mean the number of elements,

It's a tree where I have three users, each user have 15 name, and each name have 6 levels and for each level belongs 5 separate years, and finally each year has 4 items...

Comment: It's hard to say with the little information you gave.

Comment: should i explain more the tree? can you please help me to know how clarify the issue ?

Comment: `output` is supposed to be a list, so you're not talking about `output` right? What to you mean by "plot" - like a graph?

Comment: You could use a dictionary where the keys are tuples

Comment: @mtk99 what should be the keys here?

Comment: @GüntherJena
by output I just mean the final element you can call it result too, i just give it that append to clarify what i want to do in the end (it is the one I am wondering how it is supposed to be list/dic)

by plot i meant making a graph for example for user 2 to show the items (=yaxis) of every name (=yaxis) for the 3rd year in the 2nd level..

Comment: What is the final goal here? Are you looking for the fastest way to access data later? Or just simplicity of writing the code?